# LiveScript class scope this self jquery issues

Tags: livescript

```
class A
    () ->
    method: ->
    method2: ->
        $ 'a' .each ->
            href = $ @ .attr 'href'
            @method href
```

In my jQuery function I actually need both scopes, so I can't just change how the anonymous function is bound. I could put at the beginning of method2 `self = @` and then use `self.method`. I'd like to always use `self.method`. But I'd rather not put that at the beginning of every function.

Is there anyway to set up `self` in the constructor to always exist and point to `@`? Everything I tried failed. `self` was always undefined in the methods.

I put Coffeescript as a tag because it's very similar to LiveScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wavy arrow `~>` lets you carry down the context so you can avoid `self = @`:

```
method2: ->
  $ \a .each (, el) ~>
    href = $ el .attr \href
    @method href
```

Pass the jQuery element in the callback as a parameter and keep using the wavy arrow so the context will always be the instance.

Comment: Didn't realize the element was passed. Perfect.